# How do I get this guessing game to work?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a guessing game where I prompt the user to enter a secret number and he has 6 attempts to get it right. I've got most of it down, except that I can't get it to tell him once he has exhausted his tries that "sorry, you've run out, the secret number is x")

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GuessGame{
  static public void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the guessing game. I will pick a number between 1");
    System.out.println("and 100 and you will try to guess it in 6 tries or less. Here we go: ");

    for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--)
    {
      Random rand = new Random(); 
      int secNumber = rand.nextInt(5);
      int theNumber = secNumber;
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
      int guess = s.nextInt();

      if (guess == theNumber)
      {
        System.out.println("That's it! You guessed it, the number was: " +  theNumber + " and it took you " + (7 - i) + " tries.");
      }

      while(i > 0) {
      if (guess < theNumber)
      {
        System.out.println("The secret number is bigger than than that. You have " + (i - 1) + " tries left.");
        break;
      }
      else if (guess > theNumber)
      {
        System.out.println("The secret number is smaller than than that. You have " + (i - 1) + " tries left.");
        break;
      }

    }
```

To tell the user when he has zero tries left and then reveal the secret number, I tried a 
    while (i == 0)
    {
      System.out.println(....);
    }
But it kicks in immediately after the first guess.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is unnecessary, and the style is off. Here is my fix.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class GuessGame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the guessing game. I will pick a number between 1");
    System.out.println("and 100 and you will try to guess it in 6 tries or less. Here we go: ");
    int theNumber = rand.nextInt(5);
    for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
      Random rand = new Random();
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
      int guess = s.nextInt();

      if (guess == theNumber) {
        System.out.println("That's it! You guessed it, the number was: " +  theNumber + " and it took you " + (7 - i) + " tries.");
      } else if (guess < theNumber) {
        System.out.println("The secret number is bigger than than that. You have " + (i - 1) + " tries left.");
      } else if (i == 1) {
        System.out.println("You could not guess the number");
      } else {
        System.out.println("The secret number is smaller than than that. You have " + (i - 1) + " tries left.");
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but I need something explicitly for the case when i is zero, ie when the guesses are exhausted.

Comment: I fixed it for you.

Comment: thanks! but it seems like the random number keeps changing thruout the guesses. I thought I had that fixed with the 'theNumber' variable. How can I fix that?

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice that. I'm about to fix the code for that. You have it within the loop. You want it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

1. The while loop is unnecessary.
2. assign `secNumber` outside of the for loop.
3. the variable `theNumber` is unnecessary.
4. you need to replace `rand.nextInt(5)` with `rand.nextInt(100) + 1` in order to have a number between 1 and 100 inclusive.
5. Change `i - 1` to `i` because the guess count will be equal to `i`.
6. Remove `break` from if blocks, because those will make you leave the game.
7. Add `break` to the first if statement (if they won)
8. Add if statement to let the player know the game is over.

   ```
   import java.util.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class GuessGame
   {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           System.out.println("Welcome to the guessing game. I will pick a number between 1");
           System.out.println("and 100 and you will try to guess it in 6 tries or less. Here we go: ");
           Random rand = new Random();
           int secNumber = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;    // 2 4
           for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--)
           {
               Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
               System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
               int guess = s.nextInt();

               if (guess == secNumber)
               {
                   System.out.println("That's it! You guessed it, the number was: " +  secNumber + " and it took you " + (7 - i) + " tries.");
                   break;    // 7
               }
               else if (guess < theNumber)
               {
                   System.out.println("The secret number is bigger than than that. You have " + i + " tries left.");    // 5
               }
               else if (guess > theNumber)
               {
                   System.out.println("The secret number is smaller than than that. You have " + i + " tries left.");    // 5
               }

               if(i == 1)    // 8
               {
                   System.out.println("Out of tries.");
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```